Two different Ubuntu machines have the same MAC Address
I have two different orange-pi 5bs with the same MAC address I clone the ISO image. I have tried to delete the machine-id file and regenerate it. They both have the same mac address for eth0 which is very annoying the router switches the hostname and IP constantly. I have spoofed the mac address but that means turning off the etho and back on again. I also tried changing the mac address in the /etc/network/interfaces but that doesn't work either.

Are you using Ubuntu or no?  It's unclear and /etc/network/interfaces isn't how you configure Ubuntu 22.04 and later systems.

I tried the network manager config as well. I don't want it changed temporarily I want it change permanently.

Then we need to see the configurations in use on system.  From /etc/netplan and the network manager setup.  You may end up needing to configure mac addess spoofing if the issue is hardware level (i.e. the manufacturer made a mistake) and then that will 'resolve' the issue but not until we see more information to determine what's actually going on in your environment

what from network manager setup would you like to see? I went a head and spoofed the mac address in the netplan config. I would like to get to the bottom of why they are the same so if you need to see some config files just let me know which ones?
